# How to (re)generate patches from subversion commits?

Tags: svn, patch

Let's imagine a series of commits have been performed on a branch, but the branch has not been resynchronized with trunk yet. Is it possible to generate global patches from a commit? Is it possible to generate a 'grouped' patch from a series of commits? If yes, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
svn diff -rXXX:YYY URL > blah.patch
```

where `XXX` and `YYY` are the start and end revision numbers.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it is possible to achieve this from Svn Tortoise (i.e. without having to go through command line)?

Comment: @JVerstry: It's been a while since I've used TortoiseSVN.  But I'm pretty sure if you select a file/folder, go to the context menu, and select "View history" (or "View log"?), you can select two revisions, and get it to generate a diff.